# proving determinant of lower triangular matrix from definition

Tags: linear-algebra

we define $$det(A) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} (sgn\sigma)a_{1\sigma(1)}...a_{n\sigma(n)}$$ Matrix $A = (a_{ij}) $ where $a_{ij} = 0$ for $j>i$

and I want to use it to prove the determinant of a lower triangular matrix is $a_{11}...a_{nn}$

This is the proof we were given:

$\sigma = Id$ yields $(sgn Id) a_{1 id(1)}...a_{n id(n)} = a_{11}...a_{nn}$

Claim that all other terms are $0$.

So Suppose $\sigma \in S_n$ $\sigma \not = Id$ and $a_{1\sigma(1)}...a_{n\sigma(n)} \not = 0$

We prove by induction that $\sigma(i) = i, \forall i$ and hence $\sigma = Id$ but then that's supposedly the end of the proof.

I'm confused as how this shows that all other terms are $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prove the following:

$$\sigma\neq Id.\implies\;\;\exists\,i\;,\;\;1\le i\le n\;\;s.t.\;\;\sigma(i)>i$$

and from here that $\;a_{i\sigma(i)}=0\;$ ...

Comment: Would a correct proof be as follows: if $\sigma(i) \leq i$ for some $i$ then it is easy to prove inductively that $\sigma = Id$?

Comment: Well, no @Warz, as  for many $\;\sigma\neq Id.\;$  we do have that $\;\sigma(i)\le i\;$ *for some* $\;i\;$ , for example the transposition $\;\sigma:=(12)\;$: here, $\;\sigma(2)=1<2\;$ ...

Comment: mm yes but I meant generally to this question it must be $Id$, I'm not sure how to prove it generally.

Comment: Well @Warz , in general I meant. The application to this problem is another matter: $\;\sigma\neq Id.\iff \exists\,i\;\;s.t.\;\;\sigma(i)\neq i\;$